# Dialogflow's Fullfilment logic can not get Google account information

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-api, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I'd like to acquire Google account information with Dialogflow's Fullfilment logic, but the following error occurs.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 at 
  Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11) at 
  exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20) at 
  TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
```

Account linking is set up and on the client side it is certified with a Google Account. 
I can obtain user information by executing the following URL in the browser.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=foo_bar
```

However, if I access the above URL on Fulfillment, the above error will occur.
Is there a mistake in the definition below?

*Using the Fullfilment, the logic is described in index.js.

*index.js

```
'use strict';

const App = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

exports.testFunc = (req, res) => {

  const app = new App({request:req, response:res});
  let accessToken = app.getUser().accessToken;
  console.log('accessToken is ' + accessToken);

  getUserInfo(accessToken).then((output) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': output, 'displayText': output }));
  }).catch((error) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': error, 'displayText': error }));
  });
};
function getUserInfo (accessToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let https = require('https');
    let host = 'www.googleapis.com';
    let path = '/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + accessToken;
    console.log('API Request: ' + host + path);

    https.get({hostName: host, path: path}, (res) => {
      let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
      res.on('data', (d) => {
        body += d;
        console.log('data: ' + body);
      }); // store each response chunk
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('end');
        let output = `response`;
        console.log(output);
        resolve(output);
      });
      res.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

*package.json

```
{
  "name": "testFunc",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this using Firebase Functions? If so, can you include the logs from the Firebase Functions console?

Comment: Can you also add a `res.on('error', err => {...})` handler and see what that error logs?

Comment: I don't think you can do OAuth style authentication in a Cloud Function.  The code you're running expects to be running on the end user's desktop, and it will fire up their browser to ask them to log in and authorize your app to access their information.  The part of the error saying "127.0.0.1" is suggesting that the code is trying to communicate with a browser on localhost.

Comment: >To Prisoner

Thank you as always!
I defined and executed functions on Cloud Functions of Google Cloud Platform. I added the following code, but the error log was not output.

  res.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error');
    reject(error);
  });

Comment: >To Doug Stevenson

Thank you for your help.
Is there a possibility that it behaves as follows?

    1.Authenticate with Account linking on Google Assistant
    
    2.The authentication information is sent to Google and access_token is paid out
    * Authentication at this time is authentication for user's machine (browser), access_token can only be used by user's machine
    
    3.Acquire user information using access_token in GCP and fail
    * Since access_token is invalid, access is denied on the machine localhost (127.0.0.1) before reaching Google

Comment: I would like to obtain user information with Cloud Function.
Do not you know a good way?
I'm going to check for a Google API that provides account information without using account linking.

Comment: Thank you for your response. solved.
Type mistakes were the cause.
before:{hostName: host, path: path} -> after:{host: host, path: path}
I'll study harder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found your coding mistake.

typo:

```
https.get({hostName: host, path: path}, (res) => {
```

correct:

```
https.get({host: host, path: path}, (res) => {
```

Please try the above.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!! Thanks very much for your help!